# Use multiple domains (Not only sub-domains) with spatie/multitenant

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I'm using spatie/multitenant for my app and it works just fine. But now I need to implement a premium functionality allowing my customers to set their own domain.

Actually this works as follows:
Principal tenant: mydomain.com
Customers tenants: customer1.mydomain.com / customer2.mydomain.com ...

Now I required that
Customers tenants: customer1.mydomain.com / customer2.mydomain.com / otherdomain.org (For example)

I already test changing the DNS and it loads the customers login page, but when it attemps to login, it returns a 419 error (Session expires) and dont log in.

Is anything that I'm missing, or anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Change DNS
Review auth methods.